# "Data Dilemmas: The Store's New Entry Conundrum"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have created a react app with typescript and redux-tool-kit
in this app I have 4-5 crud operations and 5 different API.

For calling the API I used redux toolkit asynthunk.

My problem is when is when is click to add new data on API, `action.payload` is undefined.

I want add my data on API and store to database, but `action.payload` is undefined so I can't add data to api and api calling are not working as well.

Has anyone had this type of problem, and they get solution please help  me

Code:

TSX ->

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import ArrowBackIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import LoadingButton from "@mui/lab/LoadingButton";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Page from "../../components/Page";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { createVideo, getVideo, patchVideo } from "../../store/video/api";
import { setStatus } from "../../store/video/videoSlice";
import { AppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../store";
import { decryptString } from "../../utils/url";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Videoform: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigation = useNavigate();
  const params: any = useParams();
  const isAddMode = !params?.id;
  const subCategory = useAppSelector((state) => state.subCategory);
  const subid = subCategory.data[0].id;
  // console.log('Category ID -> ',subCategory.activeCategory.id);
  // console.log('Sub Category ID -> ',subid);

  const { handleSubmit, handleChange, resetForm,setValues } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      description: "",
      isPro: false,
      categoryId: subCategory.activeCategory.id,
      subCategoryId: subid,
      url: "",
      type: 's3', 
      activeState: false,
    },
    onSubmit: async (values): Promise<void> => {
      debugger;
      try {
        if (isAddMode) {
          debugger;
          console.log('in isadded mode',values);
          await dispatch(createVideo(values)).unwrap();
        }
        if (!isAddMode) {
          await dispatch(
            patchVideo({
              id: values.id,
              name: values.name,
              categoryId: subCategory.activeCategory.id,
              subCategoryId: subid,
              description: values.description,
              url: values.url,
              isPro: values.isPro,
              activeState: values.activeState,
            })
          );
        }
        resetForm();
        dispatch(setStatus({ status: "idle" }));
        // navigation("/video");
      } catch (error: any) {}
    },
  });


useEffect(() => {
  const fetchById = async () => {
    if (!isAddMode) {
      const decodeParam = decryptString(params.id);
      try {
        console.log("Fetching video with id:", decodeParam);
        console.log("Category ID:", subCategory.activeCategory.id);
        console.log("Sub Category ID:", subid);
        
        const record = await dispatch(
          getVideo({
            id: decodeParam,
            categoryId: subCategory.activeCategory.id,
            subCategoryId: subid,
          })
        ).unwrap();
        
        setValues(record);
      } catch (error: any) {
        navigation('/video');
      }
    }
  };
  fetchById();
}, [dispatch, isAddMode, navigation, params?.id, setValues, subCategory.activeCategory.id, subid]);


      
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Box sx={{ padding: "0 10px" }}>
        <Page title="video">
          <Container maxWidth="xl">
            <Stack
              direction="row"
              alignItems="center"
              justifyContent="space-between"
              mb={2}
            >
              <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                {isAddMode
                  ? t("module_title.add_video")
                  : t("module_title.edit_video")}
              </Typography>

              <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
                <Button
                  component={Link}
                  to="/video"
                  variant="contained"
                  startIcon={<ArrowBackIcon />}
                >
                  {t("button.back")}
                </Button>
              </Stack>
            </Stack>
            <Card variant="outlined">
              <CardContent>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        label="Name"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="standard"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        id="description"
                        name="description"
                        label="Description"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="standard"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                      <TextField
                        id="url"
                        name="url"
                        label="URL"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="standard"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            color="primary"
                            name="isPro"
                            value="ispro"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                          />
                        }
                        label={t("input.is_pro")}
                      />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            color="primary"
                            name="activeState"
                            value="active"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                          />
                        }
                        label={t("input.active_status")}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="flex-end" my={3}>
                    <Button
                      variant="text"
                      onClick={() => navigation("/video")}
                      className="cancel-button"
                      sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                    >
                      {t("button.cancel")}
                    </Button>
                    <LoadingButton type="submit" variant="contained">
                      {t("button.save")}
                    </LoadingButton>
                  </Stack>
                </form>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Container>
        </Page>
      </Box>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Videoform;
```

index.ts (action are created here and api calling )

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Video } from "../../../client/services";
import { toastHandler } from "../../../utils/toastHandler";
import { CreateVideo, FindVideo, GetVideo, PutVideo } from "./interface";

export const createVideo = createAsyncThunk(
    "Video/createVideo",
    async (values: CreateVideo, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
        console.log('in create action argument values -> ',values);
        delete (values as any)?.id;
        const response = await Video.create(values);
        console.log('responce action created -> ',response);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.error("Error in createVideo action:", error);
        toastHandler(error);
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  );


export const findVideo = createAsyncThunk(
    "Video/findVideo",
    async (values: FindVideo, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await Video.find({
                query: values,
            });

            return response;
        } catch (error: any) {
            toastHandler(error);
            return rejectWithValue(error.message);
        }
    }
);

export const searchVideo = createAsyncThunk(
    "Video/findVideo",
    async (values: FindVideo, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await Video.find({
                query: {
                    ...values,
                },
            });

            return response;
        } catch (error: any) {
            toastHandler(error);
            return rejectWithValue(error.message);
        }
    }
);

export const getVideo = createAsyncThunk(
    "Video/getVideo",
    async ({ id,categoryId ,subCategoryId }: GetVideo, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await Video.get(id, {
                query: {
                    categoryId,
                    subCategoryId
                },
            });
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        } catch (error: any) {
            toastHandler(error);
            return rejectWithValue(error.message);
        }
    }
);

export const patchVideo = createAsyncThunk(
  "Video/patchVideo",
  async (values: PutVideo, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const { id, ...patchData } = values;

    try {
      console.log('patch video ->', id, patchData);
      const response = await Video.patch(id, patchData);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error("Error in patchVideo action:", error);
      toastHandler(error);
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```

interface.ts (all types and initialstate are defined here)

```
import { STATUS_TYPE } from "../../../enum";

export interface GetVideo {
  id: string;
  categoryId: string;
  subCategoryId: string;
}

export interface FindVideo {
  search?: string | null;
  limit?: number;
  skip?: number;
}

export interface PutVideo {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  categoryId: string;
  subCategoryId: string;
  url: string;
  description: string;
  isPro: boolean;
  activeState: boolean;
}

export interface CreateVideo {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  isPro: boolean;
  categoryId: string;
  subCategoryId: string;
  url: string;
  type: string;
  activeState: boolean;
}

export interface Video {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  isPro: boolean;
  categoryId: string;
  subCategoryId: string;
  url: string;
  type: string;
  activeState: boolean;
  createdAt?: string;
  createdBy?: string;
  updatedAt?: string;
  updatedBy?: string;
}

export interface InitialState {
  data: Video[];
  skip: number;
  limit: number;
  totalRecords: number;
  currentPage: number;
  status: STATUS_TYPE;
  isError: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
}

export const initialState: InitialState = {
  data: [],
  skip: 0,
  limit: 5,
  totalRecords: 0,
  currentPage: 0,
  status: "idle",
  isError: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  errorMessage: "",
};
```

videoSlice.ts (all slice created here )

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { initialState } from "./api/interface";
import { createVideo, getVideo } from "./api";

const videoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Video",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLimit: (state, action) => {
      state.limit = action.payload;
      state.status = "idle";
    },
    setSkip: (state, action) => {
      state.skip = action.payload;
      state.status = "idle";
    },
    setCurrentPage: (state, action) => {
      state.currentPage = action.payload;
    },
    setStatus: (state, action) => {
      state.status = action.payload;
    },
    reset: () => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createVideo.pending, (state,action) => {
      debugger;
      console.log('in Video Slice CreateVideo Pending', action.payload);
      state.isLoading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(createVideo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      debugger;
      console.log('in Video Slice CreateVideo Fulfilled', action.payload);
      state.data.push(action.payload);
      state.isError = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.isLoading = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(createVideo.rejected, (state, action) => {
      debugger;
      console.log('in Video Slice CreateVideo Rejected', action.error);
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(getVideo.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getVideo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log('in Video Slice GetVideo Fulfilled', action.payload);
      state.isError = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.isLoading = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(getVideo.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log('in Video Slice GetVideo Rejected', action.error);
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
    });
  },
});

export const { setLimit, setSkip, setCurrentPage, setStatus, reset } = videoSlice.actions;
export default videoSlice.reducer;
```